# How to read a nuke script file and list its read nodes

Tags: nuke

I am aware that we can open nuke in terminal mode using -t flag.

Is there a way to open the nuke script in batch and list all the read nodes that are present.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run Python code in terminal mode just as you would in the script editor or a Python interpreter. For example:

```py
nuke.scriptOpen('/path/to/your/nukeScript.nk')
for node in nuke.allNodes(recurseGroups=True):
    if node.Class() == 'Read':
        print node.fullName(), ':', node['file'].value()
```

If you want to have Nuke execute the contents of a Python script instead, you can run it using:

```
Nuke -t /path/to/pythonScript.py
```

Comment: in case if i want to read some nukescripts (say 10 files) and list there read nodes. i need to use "Nuke -t /path/to/pythonScript.py" and have the execution code in "pythonScript.py", if that is the case, then my code in "pythonScript.py" is open to all. Instead can i use .pyc

Comment: I don't think so. And regardless, a `.pyc` file can be easily disassembled back into a raw Python script, so you wouldn't be protecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import nuke
import re

#read nuke script
nuke.scriptOpen("test.nk")

readnodes = [if re.match('Read', node['name'].value()) for node in nuke.allNodes()]
print readnodes
#this will list all the read nodes present in nuke script

nuke.quit()
```